# Pointer to good tutorial for SSL connection for iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ssl

I've scoured the web and stackoverflow for a good SSL tutorial for an iphone app.  I have been unsuccessful at finding something straightforward and easy to comprehend.  Any pointers on where to read more about it?  I just want to see how i can have a secure connection for login and data transfer via SSL.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use NSURLConnection and pass in the https based url.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html for more info.